# ¿como relaciono lo qu ese muestra en un jcombobox en funcion de lo seleccionado en el otro?

Tags: java-swing

Tengo un jcombobox de especialidades y otro con doctores. Tengo que hacer que segun la especialidad que seleccione solo me aparezcan los doctores que tienen esa especialdiad. Os dejo la inicializacion de los jcombox una foto de la interfaz y la clase doctor.

```
public void inicializarMedicos() {
        int i;
        int[] idsD = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String[] nombres = {"Elena Díaz López", "Juan Ruiz Luque", "Marta Jaén García", "Ana Pérez Martín",
            "José Guerrero Castro"};
        int[] comsultas = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
        String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General", "Medicina General", "Pediatría", "Pediatría", "Cirugía"};
        Doctor nuevoDoctor;
        listaDoctores = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i < idsD.length; i++) {
            nuevoDoctor = new Doctor(idsD[i], nombres[i], especialidad[i], comsultas[i], listaCitas);
            listaDoctores.add(nuevoDoctor);
        }
    }

    public void cargaListaMedicos() {
        int i;
        String puestoCombo3;
        for (i = 0; i < listaDoctores.size(); i++) {
            puestoCombo3 = listaDoctores.get(i).getNombreDoctor();
            cmdDoctor.addItem(puestoCombo3);
        }
    }

    public void inicializarEspecialidades() {
        List<String> listaEspecialidadesAux = new ArrayList();
        for (int x = 0; x < listaDoctores.size(); x++) {
            listaEspecialidadesAux.add(listaDoctores.get(x).getEspecialidad());
        }
        LinkedHashSet<String> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(listaEspecialidadesAux);

        String[] especialidadesSinDuplicar = linkedHashSet.toArray(new String[]{});
        int i;
        String puestoCombo2;
        for (i = 0; i < linkedHashSet.size(); i++) {
            puestoCombo2 = linkedHashSet.toString();
            cmbEspecialidad.addItem(puestoCombo2);
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es la clase doctor

```
public class Doctor {

    public static int codigo = 1;
    public String nombreDoctor;
    public String especialidad;
    public int numConsulta;
    public List<Cita> listaCitas;

    public Doctor(int codigo, String especialidad, String nombreDoctor, int numConsulta, List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        Doctor.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.numConsulta = numConsulta;
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;

    }

    public Doctor(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        codigo = Doctor.codigo++;
        this.listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getNumConsulta() {
        return numConsulta;
    }

    public void setNumConsulta(int numConsulta) {
        this.numConsulta = numConsulta;
    }

    public static int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public static void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        Doctor.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getEspecialidad() {
        return especialidad;
    }

    public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }

    public String getNombreDoctor() {
        return nombreDoctor;
    }

    public void setNombreDoctor(String nombreDoctor) {
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
    }

    public List<Cita> getListaCitas() {
        return listaCitas;
    }

    public void setListaCitas(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
    }
}
```

Comment: si usaras una base de datos, con tres tablas donde se guarden los doctores, las especialidades, y la/s especialidad /s que tiene cada doctor, sería todo mucho más sencillo y profesional. Por que así es muy de juguete el programa y además va a costar mucho ir modificando el código (escalabilidad)

Comment: Pero no puedo usar un BD porque tiene que ser asi, se pide asi